# How to access the current value of multiprocessor.value in the main process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

CODE:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import ctypes
import time

new_value = Value(ctypes.c_wchar_p, "abc")

def func():
    global new_value
    new_value.value = "xyz"
    print ('updated value to xyz')

class Test():
    
    def __init__(self):
        global new_value

    def call(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        print (new_value.value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target=func, args=())
    p1.start()
    x = Test()
    x.call()
    p1.join() # x doesn't need to wait for p1 to end but access the current value of new_value
```

OUTPUT:

```
updated value to xyz
abc
```

How do I get the current value `xyz` when accessing new_value.value from `x` object? I'm trying to access whatever the current value of `new_value` is.

Answer (score 0):

`Value` doesn't work on pointers.  A pointer in one process isn't valid in another.  Value supports numeric types or single character types.  `Value` creates a synchronized wrapper for the value that must be passed to the other Process.  It can't just be a global variable...processes don't share memory space.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def func(val):
    val.value = 'z'
    print ('updated value to z')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    value = Value('u', 'a')                   # create in main process
    p1 = Process(target=func, args=(value,))  # pass to child process
    print(value.value)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    print(value.value)
```

Output:

```
a
updated value to z
z
```

Use an `Array` for a string value:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Array

def func(arr):
    arr.get_obj().value = 'xyz'
    print ('updated value to xyz')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = Array('u', 'abc')                # create in main process
    p1 = Process(target=func, args=(arr,)) # pass to child process
    print(arr.get_obj().value)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    print(arr.get_obj().value)
```

Output:

```
abc
updated value to xyz
xyz
```